# How to authenticate user with external auth service?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

I have a microservice for logging in and user registration. After launch request on `localhost:8080` with body `{ "username": "test", "password":"test"}` i get an auth token like: `{ "token":"asdfsadfasdf..." }`,

And i must use this token in another microservice to authenticate user before launching request on my endpoint, And i have code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { AuthGuard } from "@nestjs/passport";

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

```
    @Get()
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    private async getHello(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [
        JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'secretKey',
    }),
    JwtStrategy,
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })
],
  providers: [AppService],
  controllers: [AppController]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

after launch my `Get` request i get an error:

```
[Nest] 10472   - 04.05.2021, 17:14:00   [ExceptionsHandler] Unknown authentication strategy "jwt" +3677ms
Error: Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"
```

strategy

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
    constructor() {
        super({
          jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
          secretOrKey: 'secret',
        });
    }
}
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why my auth strategy is bad?

thanks for any help!

Comment: You're gonna have to show your strategy for us to be able to help. IF I had to guess, the strategy is request scoped.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, I add strategy at the bottom, can you look?, I need to use token from external service, I know how to do this with "all in one app" but here, i have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Move your `JwtStrategy` from the `imports` to the `providers` array. Providers **never** go in the `imports` array. Only modules belong there.